# How to make OpenGL support shades of colours?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL to wrap over OpenGL in Java but apparently all colours are being converted to the basic shade. I'm not 100% sure of the english-language phrasing here, so to try and make it clearer, if I set:

```
glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0)
```

What I get in the end is the equivalent to

```
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Basically, whenever I use something that is not 0.0 in any of the red/green/blue components of a colour, I get the same behaviour that I would have had if I had used 1.0.

During OpenGL initialization I'm pretty much setting the perspective only:

```
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, DisplayManager.getWidth(), DisplayManager.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

And during rendering I'm just attempting to clear with a background colour:

```
    // clear buffer
    GL11.glClearColor(0x46, 0x82, 0xb4, 1.0f);
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Basically the background should be a blueish colour but what I get is white (which is 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0).

Is there anything (OpenGL flags or whatnot) that I need to set for this to happen? Am I just being dumb somewhere and I can't figure out where? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check that you don't cast the floats to int? In Java it may happen implicitly ... Also these - 0x46  are integers so how do you expect them to be floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GL11.glClearColor(0x46, 0x82, 0xb4, 1.0f);
```

0x46 is greater than 1.0, so it is clamped to 1.0. White.

`glClearColor` expects floats in the range 0.0 to 1.0 as inputs, not integers from 0 to 255 (0xFF).

Try this:

```
GL11.glClearColor(0x46 / 255.0f, 0x82 / 255.0f, 0xb4 / 255.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I knew I was being dumb :)